# Regex to match any character excluding \

Tags: regex

Given the string **\\Server\Folder\File.EXT**, what is the regular expression to return **\\Server\** as the match? I tried `^\\\\(.*)\\`, but that still allows for a backslash in the middle of the match, so I get **\\Server\Folder\** as the match, not **\\Server\**. Within the group I need to match any number of characters other than \ I think.

Answer (score 3):

Use [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) instead of [`.`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) in your regex.

```
^\\\\([^\\]*)\\
```

---

Or make it [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) using `?`

```
^\\\\(.*?)\\
```

Comment: Aha, I was just now trying the negation behind, not in front. And, curious since both approaches work, is one preferred over another in this scenario? Or are they both equally valid?

Comment: Well, there where two answers there. ^\\\\([^\\]*)\\ works, and so does ^\\\\(.*?)\\. The latter, the "Make it non greedy" solution seems like the better approach, but I don't know enough to be sure. And the supposed duplicate answer doesn't really seem to explain the difference in function either.

Comment: @Gordon : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41269468/3037257