# Which would be better non-greedy regex or negated character class?

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation, non-greedy

I need to match `@anything_here@` from a string `@anything_here@dhhhd@shdjhjs@`. So I'd used following regex.

```
^@.*?@
```

or

```
^@[^@]*@
```

Both way it's work but I would like to know which one would be a better solution. Regex with non-greedy repetition or regex with negated character class?

Comment: It is clear the `^@[^@]*@` option is much better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Negated character classes should usually be prefered over lazy matching, if possible.

If the regex is successful, `^@[^@]*@` can match the content between `@`s in a single step, while `^@.*?@` needs to expand for each character between `@`s.

When failing (for the case of no ending `@`) most regex engines will apply a little magic and internally treat `[^@]*` as `[^@]*+`, as there is a clear cut border between `@` and non-`@`, thus it will match to the end of the string, recognize the missing `@` and not backtrack, but instantly fail. `.*?` will expand character for character as usual.

When used in larger contexts, `[^@]*` will also never expand over the borders of the ending `@` while this is very well possible for the lazy matching. E.g. `^@[^@]*a[^@]*@` won't match `@bbbb@a@` while `^@.*?a.*?@` will.

Note that `[^@]` will also match newlines, while `.` doesn't (in most regex engines and unless used in singleline mode). You can avoid this by adding the newline character to the negation - if it is not wanted.

Comment: *Note that `[^@]` will also match newlines, while `.` doesn't* is not true without specifying the regex flavor. In POSIX, TRE and Tcl (Henry Spencer's regex library) regex flavors a dot matches line break symbols by default.

Answer (score 7):

It is clear the `^@[^@]*@` option is much better.

The negated character class is quantified *greedily* which means the regex engine grabs 0 or more chars other than `@` right away, as many as possible. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gm75dz/1) and matching:

[image]

When you use a lazy dot matching pattern, the engine matches `@`, then tries to match the trailing `@` (skipping the `.*?`). It does not find the `@` at Index 1, so the `.*?` matches the `a` char. This `.*?` pattern *expands* as many times as there are chars other than `@` up to the first `@`.

See the [lazy dot matching based pattern demo here](https://regex101.com/r/y3rxcy/1) and here is the matching steps:

[image]

Comment: Tip: The process diagrams can be found in `TOOLS` → `regex debugger`.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to ask